# c++ Template class member struct initialization syntactic sugar

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Given a class:

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    struct bar
    {
        bar(T value) { m_foo = value; }
        T m_foo;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and an instance:

```
foo<int> myfoo;
```

is it possible to create an instance of `bar` without having to specify `myfoo`'s types again like this:

```
myfoo::bar mybar;
// foo<int>::bar mybar;
```

when I try this I get an error-pair *(VS 2015)* :

> 'myfoo': is not a class or namespace name
>
> 'bar': identifier not found

**UPDATE**
here is a more detailed example of what I want to achieve:

```
template <typename T, typename T2, typename T3>
class MyClass
{
public:
    struct MyClassCreateParameters
    {
        MyClassCreateParameters( T t, T2 t2, T3 t3 )
            :
            T1Param( t ), T2Param( t2 ), T3Param( t3 ) { }

        T T1Param;
        T2 T2Param;
        T3 T3Param;
    };

    MyClass( const MyClassCreateParameters& params )
        :
        m_t1( params.T1Param ),
        m_t2( params.T2Param ),
        m_t3( params.T3Param ) { }

private:
    const T m_t1;
    const T2 m_t2;
    const T3 m_t3;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass< int, char, char* >* myclass;
    myclass = new MyClass< int, char, char* >(
        myclass::MyClassCreateParameters( 1, 'A', "abc" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post some compilable code that gives you that error.

Comment: Your use of the word "implementation" is a bit odd. Could you try to make your question clearer and use standard terminology, or expand the examples a bit?

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry for the vague question, please see the updated section for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++11 you should be able to do:

```
decltype(myfoo)::bar mybar;
```

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, I would use a typedef:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class MyClassTemplate
{
public:
    struct Params { /* ... */ };
    MyClassTemplate(Params);

    // ...
};

using MyClass = MyClassTemplate<int, char, char*>;

MyClass x(MyClass::Params(a, b, c));
```

However, you could also endow your class template with a forwarding constructor template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class MyClassTemplate
{
private:
    struct Params { /* ... */ };
    MyClassTemplate(Params);

public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    MyClassTemplate(Args ...args) : MyClassTemplate(Params(args...)) {}
    // ...
};

MyClassTemplate<int, char, char*> x(a, b, c);
```